# TFS Integration Plugin on android studio seems red and not activate or disable

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]
I tried to install the TFS integration plugin but it seems red that is mean it is disable and when i open the version control i didn't find it in drop down list, So any one can help me to use this plugin .